# How can I delete a file I uploaded to an azure function through the portal UI?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureportal

I uploaded a file with the "Upload" button, but I don't see a button anywhere to remove the file. How do I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Advanced tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings?tabs=portal#kudu) section of your Function App.

Once you're in the Kudu interface you should be able to use the [console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console) to delete the file you uploaded.

Your file is most likely in `\home\site\wwwroot`, [here](https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip20.html) is an overview of how to use Kudu.